# Why does querying a quicker view take more time?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a view, view_name, that returns 13212 records in 10.28 minutes. a change to this view was made, and now it returns 12570 records in 6.56 minutes.

I have a query which uses this view. the query is:

```
SELECT
   column1,
   column2,
   columnn
FROM
   view_name
WHERE
   column1 = 'String1'
   AND column2 = 'String2'
   AND column3 IN ('specific_string1', 'specific_string2', 'specific_stringN') //Where N = 6
ORDER BY
   column1,
   column2,
   column3
```

Before the change was made, this query would take on average 3.5 minutes to run. After the change I let it run for 20 minutes before I cancelled it. Why would a view with less records that takes less time to run by itself have such a drastic effect on this query?

****EDIT*****

Based on testing the big limiting factor on the speed is:

```
AND column3 IN ('specific_string1', 'specific_string2', 'specific_stringN')
```

If I remove that the query can run in about 7 minutes.

Comment: Because Oracle can rewrite the query and merge your query into the view query. Look at the execution plan to see what is really happening. Check the indexes and access paths being used, both for a simple query of the view and your filtered query above; and check your statistics are up to date.

Comment: When you say "on average 3.5 Minutes", resp. "after change it run for 20 Minutes" it probably means that you get data which is read from cache, resp. buffer in Oracle

Comment: The original view has a lot of logic behind it, so that could explain why those times seem high. I'll take a look at the Plan; should I check the plan of the query after the change or before the change? I would rather look at the one before the change because I know how long that one takes to run as opposed to the other one that could be running anywhere from 20 minutes to who-knows-when.

Comment: make both plans and compare them

Comment: You saying the big limiting factor is Column3,  check if you have right index created on column3

Comment: sorry about the late responses; I'm actually unable to do a lot of this (execution plan and create index) so I'm currently speaking with someone who is actually able to create these. Thank you  all for all the help. I'll keep updating with my findings until I get a solution.

Comment: If you can run the query, you can also show the execution plan: first run `explain plan for select ...;` then run `select plan_table_output 
from table(dbms_xplan.display());`